# Solving a system of linear equations with a For-loop

Tags: equation-solving, iteration

I need to find the value of `c1, c2, c3, c4` and `c5`, but the output from my code is the simplified equations, not the exact value of `c1, c2, c3, c4` and `c5`. How can I get the values of `c1, c2, c3, c4` and `c5` without having to insert those into 'Solve'?

```
n = 5;
m = n + 1;
For[i = 1; t = c, i < m, i++,
  t = 
    q Subscript[c, i - 1] - q Subscript[c, i] + 
    e (Subscript[c, i -1] Subscript[c, i]) + 
    e (Subscript[c, i + 1] - Subscript[c, i]) - 
    v Subscript[c, i] + Subscript[w, i] == 0;
  Print[Solve[t]]];
```

Comment: Do you want to solve all equations simultaneously or each separately? Also, for me, `Solve` returns the solution, but it solves for $w_i$ instead of $c_i$ - you can use the second argument of `Solve` to specify what it should solve for

Answer (score 3):

A simplified version using indexed variables rather than subscripts.

The result will become more complicated and take significantly longer to evaluate as `n` increases.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Format[c[i_]] := Subscript[c, i]
Format[w[i_]] := Subscript[w, i]

n = 2;

(eqns = q c[# - 1] - q c[#] + e (c[# - 1]*c[#]) +
       e (c[# + 1] - c[#]) - v c[#] + w[#] == 0 & /@
    Range[n]) // Column
```

[image]

```
Solve[eqns, Array[c, n]] // Simplify
```

[image]